# Unity - Deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I looked through every post related and couldn't find the solution. For me it seems like I do everything fine but I keep on getting null from Debug.Log.

This is my JSON (it was primarly array but I shrinked it to atleast figure this out and still I cant..):

```
{
  "Movement": {
    "direction": "right",
    "steps": "4"
  }
}
```

And this is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class CharacterMovementReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset movementJSON;

    [Serializable]
    public class Movement
    {
        public string direction;
        public string steps;

        public Movement (string direction, string steps){
            this.direction = direction;
            this.steps = steps;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Movement movement = new Movement("", "");
        string JSONString = movementJSON.text;
        JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(JSONString, movement);
        Debug.Log(movement.direction);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The object you're interested in is wrapped in a dictionary with one item with a key "Movement". If you want to deserialize the above json you'd probably need a wrapping object like this: 
`[Serializable] public class Wrapper { public Movement movement;}` then do `Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(); JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(JSONString, wrapper);` If you wanted to change the json, just try without the wrapping dictionary `{"direction": "right", "steps": "4"}` See [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, removing Movement field helped. However, the reason I used dictionary is because I wanted to store character path information in JSON file which requires array. Is there any other way of storing this information?

Comment: This question is about how to load a single instance of a `Movement` class. "How do I store character path information" sounds like [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

you have to use special JsonUtility to deserialize

```
var movement = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(json).Movement;
```

and to use it  add parameterless contstructor to Movement class

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Movement
    {
        ...you code

        public Movement () {}
    }
```

and Root class

```
[Serializable]
 public class Root
    {
       public Movement Movement;
    }
```

Comment: `you have to use special JsonUtility` .. OP is already doing this in `JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(JSONString, movement);` .. since OP passes in an instance of type `Movement` the compiler already knows the generic type so the `<Movement>` is redundant in OP's code ;) The parameter less constructor and the further nesting into a root class is the issue